# using the t() from react-i18next outside of a component

Tags: react-native, react-component, i18next, react-i18next

I am using i18next and react-i18next in a react native application, more specifically with input validation. I am trying to pass the t() as a parameter in a no component and i am receiving the error "TypeError: n is not a function. (In 'n('errorMessages.emailNoMatch')', 'n' is undefined)". any suggestions is highly appreciated since I am relatively new to coding and I have been searching for a couple days with this issue.

here is the i18n.js code:

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
import common_de from './translations/de/common.json';
import common_en from './translations/en/common.json';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
// Set up translations
i18next.init({
  interpolation: { escapeValue: false }, // React already does escaping
  lng: 'en', // language to use
  resources: {
    de: {
      common: common_de, // 'common' is our custom namespace
    },
    en: {
      common: common_en,
    },
  },
  debug: true,
});
export default i18next;
```

a part of the RegisterValidator.js code where I am trying to pass the t() as a parameter, but it is not reading t as a parameter inside of the switch statement.:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
// import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const RegisterValidator = (type, value, email, t) => {
  let validated = true;
  let warningMsg = [];
  switch (type) {
    case 'username':
      if (!value.includes(' ')) return [true, ''];
      else {
        warningMsg = t('errorMessages.username');
        return [false, warningMsg];
      }
    default:
      return [validated, ''];
  }
};
export default RegisterValidator;
```

and here is a part from the App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './i18n';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

function App() {
  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
      <Insert more code here />
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is the call to `RegisterValidator`?

Comment: It is called inside RegisterScreen.js, and also EditProfileScreen.js inside an Input element. however, the error only occurs inside of the RegisterValidator code that I posted. The t function works everywhere else, because I use functional components in the other files.

Answer (score 4):

What ended up working for me was calling the t function directly from i18next, and pass the namespace as a prefix to the t function.

```
import i18next from 'i18next;

const RegisterValidator = () => {
   return i18next.t('common: errorMessages.username')
}
```

Comment: note that this will not reactively update, when the user changes the language.

Comment: @Alex Spieslechner and therefore, unfortunately, pretty much useless

Answer (score 1):

You cant import the instance straight from the file where you initialize i18n.

```
import i18n from "./i18n";

...


i18n.t("required_field"); //and use it like this
```

**My i18n init file**

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";

import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import CustomLanguageDetector from "./CustomLanguageDetector";

const languageDetector = new LanguageDetector();
languageDetector.addDetector(CustomLanguageDetector);

i18n
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(languageDetector)
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    // debug: true,
    load: "languageOnly",
    backend: {
      loadPath: `/i18n/{{lng}}.json`,
    },
    react: { useSuspense: false },
    whitelist: ["pt", "en"],
    nonExplicitWhitelist: true,
    detection: {
      // order and from where user language should be detected
      order: ["CustomLanguageDetector"],
      lookupLocalStorage: "@AppName:language", //Change your appname here if you're storing the languge in local storage.
      caches: ["localStorage"],
      checkWhitelist: true,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Thanks, this at least got me one step closer. at least it is processing the t() however now I am getting the error that  'i18next::translator: missingKey en translation errorMessages.username errorMessages.username' which means that the json files are not being processed correctly, even though on all of my other files it reads it with no problems.

Comment: I added my init file for comparison, that might help. Do you have that key in your translation file?

Answer (score 0):

t() outside component won't work instead, send a message object to `RegisterValidator` and use that.

**Example -**

```
function Component() {
   // t is declared here
   const message = {
      error: t('errorMessage'),
      success: t('successMessage')
   }

   // and then send this message object to RegisterValidator
   RegisterValidator(.., .., .., message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also just export the `t` function that matters, such that you don't have to repeat `i18n.` everywhere:

**i18n init file: `translation/config`**

```js
// Some configuration of i18n
export default i18n.t;
```

**Some file using i18n**

```js
import t from 'translation/config';
t('localized-label1')
```